# Personal Computer Shut Down

Tags: shutdown

Is it ok that i will directly turn off the Automatic Voltage Regulator(AVR) without shutting the computer off?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not okay.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is harmful practice. About 30% that you will burn you hardware do this (if it has't happened already). Just try not to do this again.